# Yandex bot ходит на порт 7080

Tags: apache, nginx, порты

Сайт работает на `nginx + apache`.
`apache` крутится на порту 7080 и доступен извне (нам нужен доступ по порту 7080 к `apache` для своих целей). Но яндекс бот каким-то способом перепрыгивает на порт 7080 - это фиксирутся в логах.

Как отвадить яндекс при этом сохранить доступ по порту для себя?

Comment: Делайте постоянные редиректы на восьмидесятый в случае отсутствия какой-нибудь контрольной куки

Answer (score 1):

По-хорошему, сервисы "для себя" не должны светиться в паблик. Я вижу два варианта:

- Прикрутить OpenVPN и открыть 7080 только для клиентов внутренней
  сети.
- Если такой вариант не подходит - проксировать доступ к через
  nginx + ssl + http auth.